# Counter in in awk if else loop

Tags: awk

can you explain to me why this simple onliner does not work? Thanks for your time.

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{if($2 == i){print $0} else{print "0",i} i=i+1}' check
```

input text file with name "check":

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
e 5
f 6
g 7
```

desired output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
0 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
```

output received:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{ if($2 == i){print $0; } else{print "0",i++; print $0 } i++ }' check
```

- increment `i` one more time in the else (you are inserting a new line)
- print the currentline in the else, too
- this works only if there is only one line missing between the present lines, otherwise you need a loop printing the missing lines

Or simplified:

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{ if($2 != i){print "0",i++; } print $0; i++ }' check
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, so taking your last point into account, I used "while" instead of "if". Works like a charm, even if more than one line is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is broken because:

1. you read the next line ("e 5"),
2. $2 is not equal to your counter,
3. you print the placeholder line and increment your counter (to 5),
4. you *do not print the current line*
5. you read the next line ("f 6")
6. goto 2

A while loop is warranted here -- that will also handle the case when you have gaps greater than a single number.

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {prev = $2}
    {
        while ($2 > prev+1)
            print "0", ++prev
        print
        prev = $2
    }
' check
```

or, if you like impenetrable one-liners:

```
awk 'NR==1{p=$2}{while($2>p+1)print "0",++p;p=$2}1' check
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk '{while (++i<$2) print 0, i}1' file
```

Look:

```
$ cat file
a 1
b 2
c 3
e 5
f 6
g 7
k 11
n 14

$ awk '{while (++i<$2) print 0, i}1' file
a 1
b 2
c 3
0 4
e 5
f 6
g 7
0 8
0 9
0 10
k 11
0 12
0 13
n 14
```

Comment: Thanks. I almost didn't look at your question because you had already selected an answer. Going forward if you post other questions you might want to hold off a few hours to see what other answers you get as the first answer you get MAY not always be the best possible answer.